# Split multi-array into separate arrays by variable key

Tags: php, split, key

Suppose I have:

```
Array
    (
        [some_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => blah blah blah
            [1] => More blah.
            [2] => Stuff and things
        )

        [diff_random_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => blooh blah
        )

        [totally_new_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => interesting insights
            [1] => other.
        )
    )
```

How can I knock all these titled arrays into their own separate arrays? So it would be one array of some_title and its values, and one of diff_random_name, etc. The names are generated dynamically each time and the count of each sub-array changes too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split multidimensional array in its sub\_arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740656/split-multidimensional-array-in-its-sub-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($base as $key=>$value)
{
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Assuming $base is the name of the original array with the sub-arrays, you should be able to use $$ to treat the $key variable as the name of your new array which will give you the new arrays you want.

Comment: I appreciate the help - I have tried various ways of looping through and making new arrays[] to no avail - I tried Nathan's method as well as using $$key to create new arrays but I'm still getting one giant array as an output

Comment: what variable are you getting the output from? there should be 3 separate arrays and the original one still. if you get the output from the original then it will be unchanged. try getting output from $some_title, $diff_random_name, and $totally_new_name

Comment: Ah ok cool - that did the trick. Thanks again. I guess I'm also wrangling with how to do this in a smart way - at some point down the road after building up the arrays I'll need to split them like this, so this is very helpful.

Comment: to be honest i'm not sure this is the best way to go. typically we leave them all in the original array and use a foreach loop to iterate over all of them. otherwise you won't know what the name of your new arrays will be if they are dynamically generated...

Comment: No worries - my real problem was that eventually I'll have to send them all off for separate processing to an external service and was mostly worried about how to access them at the changing-title level, so $$key is a good trick

Comment: foreach($base as $key=>$value) You can just use the loop. $key will be the name of the table and $value will be the subarray.