# Split multidimensional array in its sub_arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, split, woocommerce, sub-array

I have just had this issue. I have a multidimensional array ($varianti) that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [pa_taglia] => Array
        (
            [0] => l
            [1] => m
        )

    [pa_colore] => Array
        (
            [0] => blu
            [1] => giallo
            [2] => rosso
        )

)
```

What I need is to get different arrays for each sub array so I need this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => l
    [1] => m
)
Array
(
    [0] => blu
    [1] => giallo
    [2] => rosso
)
```

The main problem is that I can get as many sub-arrays as needed (this is for my Woocommerce plugin to create product_variations from attributes) so it needs to be flexible.

This is the code I came up with (after 2 hours...):

```
$keys = array_keys($varianti);//get the main keys

        //split multidimensional array in sub arrays
        foreach ($keys as $key=>$val){          
            $nr_var[$val]= count($varianti[$keys[$key]]);//create array such as array('key1'=> qty1, 'key2'=> qty2);
            $$val = $varianti[$keys[$key]];//create a variable variable from key
        }
        print_r($nr_var);
        foreach ($nr_var as $chiave=>$valore){
            print_r($$chiave);//retrieve values calling variable variable
        }
```

I hope this may be of help to anyone.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is? if you have the solution to your own answer then you should post it as a answer instead of a extension of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://php.net/extract) function which will automatically create new variables basing on the key values:

```
extract($varianti);
var_dump($pa_colore);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `extract()` function of PHP. this function extract array in variable format.

Consider this is in `$main_array`

```
Array
(
    [pa_taglia] => Array
        (
            [0] => l
            [1] => m
        )

    [pa_colore] => Array
        (
            [0] => blu
            [1] => giallo
            [2] => rosso
        )

)

extract($main_array);

print_r($pa_taglia);
print_r($pa_colore);
```

For more detail refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0):

You can just get them by key and store them in a variable.

```
$array1 = $varianti["pa_taglia"];
$array2 = $varianti["pa_colore"];

var_dump($array1);
var_dump($array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have got the all global variable using `get_defined_vars();` of your program ,which you obviously be multidimensional array.
After that i am access their key with `array_keys($orignalArr);`.
Then finally display every subarray by their key value.

```
$orignalArr = get_defined_vars();
$keyArr=array_keys($orignalArr);
$arrCount=sizeof($keyArr);
echo  "Values of keys<br><br>";
for($i=0;$i<$arrCount;$i++)
{
echo "<br/>";
print_r($keyArr[$i]);
echo "==";
print_r($orignalArr[$keyArr[$i]]);
echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: this is not a particularly useful answer, as not only is the indentation off and makes it almost unreadable - but it is entirely undocumented and without explanation. Please provide this, just so that the user can evaluate this as an answer to accept or not.